# How can I determine which call to a resource is failing?

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, png, google-chrome-devtools

I get this err msg in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools:

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) http://localhost/%3C%=%20System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[%22ThisApp%22]%20%%3E/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png*

...yet that image does exist, in that location, and elsewhere loads fine (I see it later in the Network stack with a Status Code of 304). So how do I determine which reference to that image is bad?

Some places are referencing that file like this:

```
background-image: url('/@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"]/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png');
```

...but others are using this old-fashioned style:

```
background:#344f9b url('/<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"] %>/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png') repeat-x 0 -368px;
```

Comment: I highly doubt that `http://localhost/%3C%=%20System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[%22ThisApp%22]%20%%3E/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png` exists.

Comment: In particular, you're using Razor and ASPX code in files that aren't preprocessed.

Comment: So I should convert all the references to that .png to be of the first format? I'm not sure why that is better than referencing "/TLDReporter/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png" (TLDReporter is the name of the project).

Comment: Where have you put `background-image: url('/@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"]/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png'); `? If this is in your css file then this is where your problem is.

Comment: It's all over the place; I think this app was created over years in a sort of helter-skelter/"You're pregnant again? I'll nail another room onto the back of the shed" fashion. A few places are the <style> sections of Application.Master, _Layout.cshtml, and various and sundry other spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks as though you are attempting to put Razor code and/or asp.net inline scripting into an external stylesheet. This is not possible as far as I am aware.

So basically your backgrounds are rendering with the image url as being either

```
`/@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"]/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png`
```

or

```
`/<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"] %>/Content/Images/SSCSsprite.png`
```

Which are then in turn being URL Encoded.

I would suggest that you update your background image references.

Comment: "Update" as in change them all to the razor style?

Comment: If they are in the external stylesheet then no, you can't put Razor into it. You need to have the actual path. You could put the `background-image` styles within your `_Layout` page and add the Razor script into it though.

Comment: No, it's all in-line stuff; not much in the way of external CSS files are used yet, except for the 3rd-party CSS files.